# Is there any way of configuring Play Store Monetization for receiving (RTDN)⁠ in backend QA environment?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-play-console

I need to test paying for my app subscriptions and receiving real-time developer notifications (RTDN)⁠ on the backend for the QA environment. In the monetization configuration, there is only one Pub/Sub topic configuration for the production environment. Since I need to test a new back-end implementation, it would be nice to have another setup for the Pub/Sub topic for the QA environment.

So, Is there any way of configuring Play Store Monetization for receiving (RTDN)⁠ in backend QA environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can't add multiple Pub / Sub topics into the Google Play Store console.

However if you need to send messages to different API endpoints, you can create multiple subscriptions to the Pub / Sub topic assigned to the Google Play Store.

You would create 1 subscription per API endpoint and assign each the different endpoint url.